# Beall's List of Potential Predatory Publishers on Weebly shutdown?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, disreputable-publishers, harassment

Most academics would be familiar with Beall's list of Potential Predatory Publishers.  [His project was shutdown](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/01/18/librarians-list-predatory-journals-reportedly-removed-due-threats-and-politics) some years ago, with the publicised reason being a "personal decision" (see link above), but it is widely acknowledged this was due to targeted harassment and pressure from publishers on the list and potential lawsuits.

However, many academics continue to rely on lists like his to help differentiate between legitimate and predatory journals, publishers, and even conferences.  As a result, Beall's original list was preserved on other websites and extended to add new entities as they were created.

One such website was ["BEALLSLIST.NET" (http://beallslist.weebly.com/)](http://beallslist.weebly.com/) which contained Bea'lls original list and extended version.  I regularly used this site when asked to review articles in journals I am not familiar with.  However, recently (sometime since Oct 2019 by my estimate), **this site also appears to have been shutdown**.

Why (and when) was this site taken down? Was this due to targeted harassment from publishers too? Are there any other good alternative sources that contain Beall's original list and extended lists?

Comment: I have found one alternative website, which contains Beall's original list, but it has been merged with new updates:
https://predatoryjournals.com/journals/.  

And a separate one for publishers: 
https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the answer.  There is a lengthy discussion about archived versions of Beall's list on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_reliable_is_the_Bealls_List_of_predatory_journals).  It seems that the original list that was archived at https://beallslist.weebly.com/ is in the process of moving to a new website: https://beallslist.net/.

One user on ResearchGate quoted the new web host: "We are in the process of migrating from Weebly to an independent server. Contact form is currently disabled but will be working soon."

So the situation is not dire - they are migrating, not being shutdown. Phew!  It is good that other alternatives exist as well.